# What's wrong with my solution to Project Euler 17?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve Project Euler Problem 17, and I've debugged this code many times. However, I'm getting 22048, which is wrong. Here is the problem:

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?
>
> NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

Could you help me to figure out how to fix my Python solution please?

```
    key = {
1: 'one',
2: 'two',
3: 'three',
4: 'four',
5: 'five',
6: 'six',
7: 'seven',
8: 'eight',
9: 'nine',
10: 'ten',
11: 'eleven',
12: 'twelve',
13: 'thirteen',
14: 'fourteen',
15: 'fifteen',
16: 'sixteen',
17: 'seventeen',
18: 'eighteen',
19: 'nineteen',
20: 'twenty',
30: 'thirty',
40: 'forty',
50: 'fifty',
60: 'sixty',
70: 'seventy',
80: 'eighty',
90: 'ninety',
100: 'hundred',
1000: 'thousand',
}
sum = 0

def digits(number):
    return [int(i) for i in str(number)]

for num in range(1, 1001):
    if num <= 20:
        sum = sum + len(key[num])
    elif num <= 99:
        sum = sum + len(key[((digits(num))[0] * 10)])
        if (digits(num))[1] != 0:
            sum = sum + len(key[(digits(num))[1]])
    elif num <= 999:
        tridig = digits(num)
        sum = sum + tridig[0] + len(key[100]) + 3 # for the "and"
        lasttwo = tridig[1] * 10 + tridig[2]
        if lasttwo > 0:
            if lasttwo <= 20:
                sum = sum + len(key[lasttwo])
            else:
                sum = sum + len(key[((digits(lasttwo))[0] * 10)])
                if (digits(lasttwo))[1] > 0:
                    sum = sum + len(key[(digits(lasttwo))[1]])
    else:
        sum = sum + len(key[1000])

print sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem lies in the `elif num < 999` block - you're adding the count of 'and' before checking if there are more digits.  Your code would benefit from using a separate function to count the letters of a number, then you could call it recursively when counting 'four hundred and' x.

You've got another problem in the case of 1000, but that one should be easier to find so I'll leave that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If `lasttwo == 0` then there's no 'and' (200 is 'two hundred', not 'two hundred and'), but you add 3 for 'and' before you test `if lasttwo > 0`.